# How to combine a .MP4 video with a .WAV audio to create a new .MP4 video using ffmpeg from command line arguments?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, wav, mp4

I want to merge a .WAV audio file with a .MP4 video file to create a new .MP4 video file.

And i am currently using the following codes to do that :

```
ffmpeg -i input_vid.mp4 -i input_audio.wav -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
```

But it is only creating output.mp4 file but no videos embedded with that means if i am playing that output.mp4 file then nothing is playing.
And i don't know where i am doing wrong so that it is creating like this.

I know this type of questions already asked by may persons but that didn't help me much so if anybody can find where i am doing wrong or how to solve this problem please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Remove `-acodec copy`. That option forces a direct copy of WAV bytes into MP4's audio track. A valid MP4 must contain MPEG audio (mp3 or aac). Once removed then FFmpeg will still copy video part but also auto encode from WAV to AAC for you.

Comment: Thanks @VC.One, It works for me after removing `-acodec copy` .

Comment: Glad it's sorted. Will add as solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `-acodec copy`. That option forces a direct copy of the WAV bytes into MP4's audio track.

A valid audio MP4 must contain an MPEG audio track (mp3 or aac). Once you remove `-acodec copy` then FFmpeg will still `copy` the video (picture) part but also automatically encode from WAV to AAC for you. AAC is the standar audio codec inside MP4 files (can add MP3 too since all 3 formats are compatible MPEG files).